# Check the render method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am using react, redux and react-redux-router. When I run an application I get an error. I do not understand what it has to do with the render function of react in my App.js. It seems to me that problem is lying somewhere else in the code.

The error are as follows:

```
 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `App`.
 in App
 in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
 in ConnectedRouter
 in Provider       
 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `App`.
```

My javascript App file code is shown below.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Header from './common/Header';
 import HomePage from '../components/home/HomePage';
 import Routes from '../routes';            
 const App = () => (
   <div>
   <Header />              
   <Routes />
   </div>
     )

 export default App;
```

my Javascript index file code is shown below

```
 import 'babel-polyfill';
 import React from 'react';
 import {render} from 'react-dom';
 import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
 import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
 import configureStore, {history} from './store/configureStore';
 import {loadProducts} from './actions/homeAction';
 import routes from './routes';
 import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
 import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';
 import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
 import App from './components/App';    

  const store = configureStore();
  store.dispatch(loadProducts("http://localhost:1219/portal/getProducts"));        
 render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
     <App />
     </ConnectedRouter>
     </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Any help would be appreciated. If you would like more detail please let me know

Comment: Are you sure the `import App from './components/App';` statement is correct?

Comment: check the export of `Header`, `HomePage` and  `Routes` components. if you are not exporting them default you need to import them like `import { Home } from '/path/to/Home/component.js'`. Can you post snippets from these components please

Comment: Yes, I am sure import statement for App is correct. I am using visual code. when I mouse hover på this statement. It shows me a correct path to the App.js file

Comment: I checked export statement for Header, Homapage and Routes components. I am using default for all

Comment: ROUTEJS Code

import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';

export default (   
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />    
);

Comment: HEADERJS Code

import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


const Header = () => {
    return(
        <nav>
            <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
        </nav>
    );
};


export default Header;

Comment: HOMEJS Code

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getProducts} from '../../actions/homeAction';

class HomePage extends React.Component{
  ...................

    }
    
   

HomePage.propTypes ={
    products:React.PropTypes.array,
    getProducts: React.PropTypes.func
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    debugger;
    return {      
        products: state.products       
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);

Comment: your routejs seems off. `export default () => ( <Route ... /> )` should fix it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have resolved the issue. There was a problem with my App.js file.

Comment: @user3661407 can you tell me that how you fix this problem i am also facing the same problem.thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me it seemed like I had to remove the `MemoryRouter` or `ConnectedRouter` in your case.

Also, note that my issue was in my `App.test.js` file so it may not apply to OP's specific use case but it might help those of you whom arrived here through Google.

Can someone please explain why this works?

This is the code that is now working:

```js
<Provider store={store}>
     <App />
</Provider>
```

This is the original non-working code:

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else having this problem, ensure you have an export default for any component you use in your route, else you will run into this error.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this type of issue. Do not forget our best friend in javascript!

React has made it clear that you have a problem in the `<App />` component, so first try to do `console.log(App)` in your index to see what it returns.

Then dig down by removing components 1 by 1 in the `<App />` to see which one causes the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

In your **App.js** file when you are importing the components make sure you write then in `{}`

like below

```
import {Header} from './common/Header';
import {HomePage} from '../components/home/HomePage';
```

This will resolve the issue.

If you have some default export components that you can mention without {}.

like below

```
import Header from './common/Header';
```

If you have multiple components in one js file, you can write as below

```
import Header,{OtherComponent1,OtherComponent2} from './common/Header';
```

Comment: default exports can be imported without {}